# Aggregating data from Parse columns

Tags: parse-platform

Using Parse for the backend of my app. If I want to isolate data from a single column within a class (a la Excel spreadsheet column, to get a numerical sum of the data), is there a way to export a single column as numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Parse doesn't have any aggregating queries like SQL, so your only option is to either keep totals updated using afterSave handlers (very common pattern), or get all the rows and aggregate the data yourself (queries are limited to 100 rows by default with 1000 as the max, so this option has issues).

To see an example of the afterSave pattern, look at this documentation:

https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#functions-aftersave